# How to create a virtual network interface in linux. Then redirect all traffic from it to socks5?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, socks

How to create a virtual network interface in linux. Then redirect all traffic from it to socks5 (example: `127.0.0.1:666`) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here.

Comment: @kaylum The question is implicitly asking how to write a program to do this thing.